# Micrometer stackdriver registry. Understanding distribution

Tags: java, micrometer, google-cloud-monitoring

I am in the process of switching over from influxdb to google cloud monitoring via micrometer. In influxdb, published metrics are very easy to make sense of. Though in stackdriver's case it's very confusing. Taking one micrometer timer as an example, on the google cloud monitoring metric explorer, i see three custom metrics for selection when timer metrics are published to it:

1. count
2. max
3. DISTRIBUTION

Now i have gone over the whole gcloud monitoring documentation to understand what DISTRIBUTIONS are. But when I try to fiddle with it, the only useful thing i get out of it is through the 'mean' aggregator. Selecting other aggregators does nothing. Choosing the aligner in advance options menu produces different results for 'next older' and 'sum'. The rest of percentile options give back just the value 0.

What I don't understand is that if micrometer publishes separate metrics for count and max then why dont they do that for mean as well. Why use DISTRIBUTION instead and using it in a such a way that only the 'mean' aggregator produces something meaningful.

Am I doing something wrong here? Hard to understand what because the same timer generates metrics that look completely fine in influxdb but produces a confusing mess in google cloud monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

To make better sense of distribution in stackdriver try to use following timer configuration:

```
Timer.builder("request.latency")
        .tag("tag", "tagValue")
        .publishPercentileHistogram()
        .minimumExpectedValue(Duration.ofMillis(100))
        .maximumExpectedValue(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .register(meterRegistry);
```

Or if you want to use your own SLO to generate buckets:

```
Timer.builder("request.latency")
        .tag("tag", "tagValue")
        .serviceLevelObjectives(
            Duration.ofMillis(100),
            Duration.ofMillis(200),
            Duration.ofMillis(400),
            Duration.ofMillis(600),
            Duration.ofMillis(800),
            Duration.ofMillis(1000))
        .register(meterRegistry);
```

With similar configuration I was able to use percentile aggregations and generate heatmap chart.

I also tried to follow [google tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census#monitoring_opencensus_metrics_quickstart-java) for custom metrics using opencensus and got more manageable metrics. Feels like micrometer stackdriver using slightly different logic configuring metrics. For instance it uses gauge metric kind for distributions.

Also worth checking [supported metric kinds and types](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/kinds-and-types#kind-type-combos). Not all of them are applicable for custom metrics.